# Añadir filas en diferentes tablas

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.7

Tengo que agregar un producto a 2 tablas diferentes. Por lo que estuve leyendo tengo que usar BEGIN TRANSACTION para iniciar la consulta y luego COMMIT TRANSACTION para terminarla. Al realizar lo anterior me da este error **TypeError: Cursor.executescript() takes exactly one argument (2 given)**.Si tienen alguna solución o ayuda me serviría mucho. Adjunto el código

```
def agregar_producto(self):
    # variables

    codigo = self.codigo.get()
    nombre = self.nombre.get()
    cantidad = self.cantidad.get()
    tipo = self.tipo.get()
    precio_v = self.precio_venta.get()
    precio_c = self.precio_compra.get()

    # conexión
    db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
    conexion = db.cursor()
    
    # consulta
    if codigo != '' and nombre != '' and cantidad != '' and tipo != '' and precio_v != '' and precio_c != '':
        conexion.executescript('BEGIN TRANSACTION ; INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?); INSERT INTO stock INSERT INTO stock VALUES(NULL,NULL,?,?); COMMIT;',(codigo, nombre, cantidad, tipo, precio_v, precio_c))
        conexion.close()
        db.commit()
        self.codigo.set('')
        self.nombre.set('')
        self.cantidad.set('')
        self.tipo.set('')
        self.precio_venta.set('')
        self.precio_compra.set('')
        self.ventana_agregar.destroy()
        self.cargar_productos()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'ERROR', message = 'Para continuar, necesita completar todos los campos!')
```

Comment: `executescript` requiere que le pases un string con los comandos complementamente formateados.

Comment: No te entiendo, de que manera lo haría?

Comment: Revisa este enlace: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-execute-many-sqlite-statements-in-python/

Comment: Gracias, lo revise pero ya que 'executescript' solo admite 1 argumento, no me explica como puedo usar la variables que obtuve con el método .get().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un script sql:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ; 
INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL,codigo,nombre,cantidad,tipo); 
INSERT INTO stock INSERT INTO stock VALUES(NULL,NULL,precio_v,precio_c); 
COMMIT;
```

Un script sql, nada que ver con Python, PHP, Javascript ni nada. Es SQL, sintaxis SQL, se ejecuta dentro de una base de datos ...

Si quieres hacerlo desde Python, colocas eso dentro de un string:

```
comando = """
BEGIN TRANSACTION ; 
INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL,codigo,nombre,cantidad,tipo); 
INSERT INTO stock INSERT INTO stock VALUES(NULL,NULL,precio_v,precio_c); 
COMMIT;
"""
```

y luego llamas al método

```
conexion.executescript(comando)
```

Nota: No sé si el script es válido o no, o si es el formato adecuado (parece que el segundo INSERT se duplicó accidentalmente). Sólo te transmito el **formato** en que debes entregarlo.